# Show key bindings in editline

Tags: macos, terminal, keybindings

In the [`man` page for `.editrc`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/editrc) a command is shown for listing key bindings for editline. Editline is a library that is used in Python and MySQL, etc., in MacOS for command line editing.

```
bind
```

or

```
bind -l
```

I can enter one of these commands in my `~/.editrc` and start an application such as Python which is bound to the editline library and get the output. However there is no indication how to obtain the list interactively from the command line.

Issuing a `bind` command from `zsh` gives a command not found error. Zsh uses its own key bindings and has a `bindkey` command. Bash uses readline and has a `bind` command but that's a builtin that's specific to Bash and readline.

How can I output the list without adding the command to `.editrc`?

Comment: @allan It's about listing the key bindings defined in `~/.editrc` on macOS. As this is only used by 3rd party binaries like Python or MySQL there is no macOS man page for this.

Comment: You’re correct @nohillside, I missed the macOS references in the beginning.  Retracted my vote

Comment: @nohillside: "... no macOS man page..." The system install of Python 3 uses editline. Python is, of course, third-party but it's provided by Apple. There's a man page for editrc in `/usr/share/man/man5/editrc.5` which I presume was part of the base install provided by Apple. I used the link in my answer because I couldn't find a link to an Apple-provided online page for it. Perhaps I should have used the [FreeBSD](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=editrc&sektion=5&format=html) one but it's incomplete. [Here's](https://manpages.org/editrc/5) a neutral one that's complete.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't bother to check, thanks. But how I read the man page, commands like `bind` can only be used in `~/.editrc`: `The format of each line is: [prog:]command [arg [...]]`, `command is one of the editline(3) builtin commands`, and `bind` is listed as one of them.

Comment: @nohillside: I just think it's odd for a config file to produce output to `stdout`.  The `history` command also does it.